# if C equals three fractions, what is the value of C?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, fractions, number-comparison

$$ c = \frac{30}{7}\cdot \frac{999}{300} \cdot \frac{699}{100}$$
What is the value of c ? Is  it smaller than 10? between  100 and 1000 ?
between 10 and 100? or smaller than 1000?

How can i find that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{30}{7}\cdot\frac{999}{300}\cdot\frac{699}{100}=\frac{999\cdot699}{7\cdot1000}=\frac{999}{1000}\cdot\frac{699}{7}<1\cdot100=100.$$
In another hand,

$$\frac{30}{7}\cdot\frac{999}{300}\cdot\frac{699}{100}=\frac{999\cdot699}{7\cdot1000}=\frac{999}{1000}\cdot\frac{699}{7}=\left(1-\frac{1}{1000}\right)\left(100-\frac{1}{7}\right)>$$
$$>100-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{7}>99.$$